# exponentiation of cardinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that $a^{x}\leq b^{y}$ for any cardinal number a,b, $x,y$ with a$\leq$b , $x\leq y$?

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to use an injection $a\to b$ and an injection $x\to y$ to construct an injection $a^x\to b^y$. The possibility of using the definitions directly should always be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assume that $b > 0$. The case of $a = b = 0$ holds trivially.

Let $A, B, X, Y$ be sets with cardinalities $a, b, x, y$. We may identify $A$ and $X$ with subsets of $B$ and $Y$, respectively. Thus, we may consider $A \subset B$ and $X \subset Y$.

Let $b_0 \in B$ and fix $b_0$. (We can do this since $b > 0$.)

Now we define an injection $\Phi:A^X \to B^Y$.
Let $f \in A^X$. That is, let $f: X\to A$ be a function. We define $\Phi(f):Y\to B$ as
$$\Phi(f)(t) = \begin{cases}f(t) & t \in X\\ b_0 & t \notin X \end{cases}$$

It is easy to see that $\Phi(f)$ is well-defined for all $f\in A^X$ and that $\Phi$ is an injection.